# In React Native, the method of BackHandler does not work until back root route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

when I press physical return button on my phone the log have no output until back root route

```
componentWillMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBackAndroid)
}

_onBackAndroid = () => {
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.routeName)
    if (this.lastBackPressed && this.lastBackPressed + 2000 >= Date.now()) {
        return false;
    }
    this.lastBackPressed = Date.now();
    toastShort('Press Again Exit App');
    return true;
};

componentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBackAndroid)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, react-navigation takes full control of the back button unless you handle the state yourself (by using something like Redux).

You can take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/455), which is referencing a similar situation.